# из Mysql все данные приходят в string, как получить нужный тип?

Tags: php, mysql

Сервер

```
Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u1 (2017-12-23) x86_64
Mysql 5.7
PHP 7.2
```

Таблица в базе

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `project` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `text` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
    COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
```

Скрипт PHP

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','****','****','***');
$product_name = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = 1")->fetch_object();
var_dump($product_name); 
$mysqli->close();
```

Ответ сервера

`object(stdClass)#3 (4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["user"]=> string(1) "1" ["project"]=> string(1) "2" ["text"]=> string(10) "Текст" }`

через PDO пробывал, так же все в string

т.е всегда получаю string, может какой то модуль поставить надо ? Все ставил из стандартных репозиториев и настройки по умолчанию
Хостинг Timeweb

Comment: У вас вроде `PHP`, зачем вам конкретные типы?) P.S. `string` - от mysql - это нормальное поведение.

Comment: https://cs5.pikabu.ru/post_img/2015/12/04/5/1449210847155432089.jpg

Comment: Удобнее работать с нужными типами данными прямо из базы, эти же данные потом идет в JS, а там стринга на стрингу не умножаются

Comment: Насколько я знаю, причина проблемы - используемый формат обмена драйвер <=> БД: он текстовый, числа, строки, даты идут обычным текстом без уточнения типа. Это значит, нужна доп преобразование в явном или неявном виде.

Comment: так это я и так понял, я не могу найти нужной информации, как это исправить

Comment: посмотрите аналогичный вопрос на SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323146/mysql-integer-field-is-returned-as-string-in-php

Comment: Гугл говорит что это стандартное поведение драйвера php mysql. Что бы были корректные типы необходимо использовать драйвер mysqlnd (драйвер указан в php.ini и возможно требуется сборка php с его поддержкой)

Comment: Mike, я находил подобную информацию. Вызывю в этом же скрипте phpinfo() и мне выдает https://yadi.sk/d/oNs_CRkf3ZxyGk

Answer (score 3):

Не всегда string приходит, обманываете! если будет `NULL` - то вернётся именно нормальный php-шный `null`. Остальное всё можно и ручками привести.

Можно получать нужные типы. Легко (вру, тяжко и муторно):

```
/**
 * Костыле-функция для получения PDO типа по native_type
 * @param string $native_type
 * @return int
 */
function getPDOType($native_type) {
    switch ($native_type) {
        case 'LONG':
            return PDO::PARAM_INT;
        // ...
        case 'VAR_STRING':
        default:
            return PDO::PARAM_STR;
    }
}

$pdo  = db::connect();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 600;');
$stmt->execute();
$col_cnt = $stmt->columnCount();
$row     = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $col_cnt; $i++) {
    $meta = $stmt->getColumnMeta($i);
    $stmt->bindColumn(
        $i + 1,
        $row[$meta['name']],
        getPDOType($meta['native_type'])
    );
}
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
var_dump($row);

//array(2) {
//    ["id"]   => &int(600)
//    ["tema"] => &string(9) "Чебурашка"
//}
```

Посмотрите также пример в [документации](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php#example-982).
Описание большей части параметров PDO::FETCH_* есть [тут](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo/fetch).

Но я бы не стал использовать такой способ. С другой стороны, если написать ему какую-нибудь функцию-обёртку, которая будет "всё делать за меня" - возможно и пригодилось бы для чего-нибудь.

Comment: Я беру какой нибудь хостинг на timeweb , запускаю там тот же скрипт который выше привел и все типы данных приходят корректно. А то что Вы предлагаете, это совсем не верный подход

Comment: @ДенисЗахаренко, извиняюсь, но я лично извращенством считаю вместо разбора проблемы и поиска решения - пытаться постоянно прикрутить какой-нибудь модуль. Но я же Вам об этом не пишу. Вы задали конкретный вопрос - можно ли получать данные нужных типов. Я дал конкретный ответ - "можно" и привёл пример как это сделать. Сейчас же Вы почему-то пишете "и все типы данных приходят корректно" - так у Вас получаются на выходе нужные Вам типы или нет? К чему тогда вообще был Ваш изначальный вопрос?

Comment: мой вопрос был к тому, как сделать получения типа данных корректным из базы, как это у всех хостингов реализовано. По Вашему примеру я мог бы просто сделать $string=(int)$user->id; и получу int на выходе

Comment: @ДенисЗахаренко, да что же это такое-то! Вы всё твердите "как это у всех как это у всех" - да приведите уже пример - где это есть-то? Дополнил свой ответ - теперь тип берётся по native_type из PDO-функции. Дальше как улучшить ещё - я уже не придумаю, просто нет информации (известную информацию по PDO я пересмотрел, а писать свой модуль к PHP для взаимодействия с БД я собираюсь только в глубокой старости).

Comment: Я писал выше, что на хостинге TimeWeb, так же пробывал reg.ru